# Media query (min-width: 1392px) is being applied at width less than 1392px, why?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am working on a live website http://adminwp.gameszeit.de/ In the last lines of style.css file I have used the following code:

```
@media (min-width: 720px) {
    .pstgms > li {
        width: 147.6px ;

    }
}
@media (min-width: 1392px) {
    .pstgms > li {
        width: 152.8px;

    }
}
```

Now whn I open inspect the `.pstgms > li` element on screensize lesser than 1392px, the query within `(min-width: 1392px)` is still being applied. You can check it yourself by opening the developer tools. My question is,

> How can a media query of (min-width: 1392px) be applied at width less than 1392px?

Following is screen shot at media width 1280 pixels. You can see blue circled query on the right size is overridden by (min-width: 1392px)

[image]

Comment: Please post ax exmaple of your HTML content, not a link to a site. You can also make a snippet to imporve the quality of your question.

Comment: Try this @media only screen and (min-width:1392px){ }

Comment: In my browsers works fine: Firefox, Chrome, IE11

Comment: @blonfu Which screen size are you using?

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ The problem can't be recreated in a sample example. Because it would one month to replicate it in a small code that could be posted on stackoverflow

Comment: I resize the browser and media queries work fine, less than 1392px applies the 720px media queries and less than 720px the default styles

Comment: @blonfu I don't know how's that possible. I've tested on three different devices with different screen sizes. I also used full hd monitor. Let me add the screenshots.

Comment: @blonfu I've added the snapshot.

Comment: I see. Is strange, look my firefox: https://postimg.org/image/gl1n9uitj/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114914/discussion-between-blonfu-and-user31782).

Comment: Your page is impossible to debug to us, since you're changing it all the time. If you have a question about a particular situation, please post a static version of that situation rather than something which is a moving target.

Comment: @MrLister My senior developer fixed the issue. I don't know why his media queries worked. Now this question is meaningless.

Comment: Maybe the css files were being changed so often that the browsers were always a couple of versions behind. Css files do tend to be cached.

Comment: @MrLister Not only I removed cache with `Ctrl + shift + delete ` I tested on other computers -- where the website had never been loaded -- as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure (because i'm using chrome), but when i'm looking at your devtools screenshot  it seems that 'media' is missing/stripped after the '@'. Is this normal behavior in FF?

Answer (score -2):

```
@media only screen and(min-width: 720px) {
    .pstgms > li {
        width: 147.6px ;

    }
}
@media only screen and(min-width: 1392px) {
    .pstgms > li {
        width: 152.8px;

    }
}
```

only media_type: @media is not define the proper specification. so that you are use media_type either you use   media_type: @media all |  aural | braille | handheld | print |  projection | screen | tty | tv | embossed

Comment: I've tried with `only` too. Infact I have tried everything like `all`, `print` etc etc.

Comment: you mention .pstgms > li { width: ..} only in media query section..?.